# How can i use two different DataContexts in a Custom Control in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, datacontext

In my WPF C# .NET 8 Application i have a Custom Control which is a CustomDateTime Control that collects and display partial dates like this:

[image]

The issue i am facing now is that the DataContext of the CustomControl is set to `this.DataContext = this` in the ctor of the CustomControl, and when i try use the `Date` Property like this `Date="{Binding DataItems/Date}"` in the XAML i found that nothing is displayed in the control because the DataContext is changed to the ViewModel, and when i set the DataContext to `this` the `Date` Property will not receive Data.

Now how can i make the `Date` Property to use the DataContext provided by the user in `Date="{Binding DataItems/Date}"` and the `Year`, `Month` and `Day` Properties to use `this` as the DataContext so that they work as displayed in the gif above?

*HERE ARE MY CODES:*

**the Style in Generic.xaml:**

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDateTime}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDarkBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDateTime}">
                    <Grid FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBox x:Name="dummyTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Date, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Foreground="Black"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             TextAlignment="Right" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{Binding Path=(materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"                            
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.10"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                             IsTabStop="False"
                             IsHitTestVisible="False"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="YearTextBox"  
                             Grid.Column="0" 
                             Foreground="Black"
                             Text="{Binding Year, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             TextAlignment="Left"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Year" 
                             materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.RippleOnFocusEnabled="True"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.25"
                             TabIndex="0" 
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             Opacity="0.001"
                             Margin="10 0 0 0"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="MonthTextBox"  
                             IsEnabled="False"
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Text="{Binding Month, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             TextAlignment="Left"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Month" 
                             materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.RippleOnFocusEnabled="True"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.25"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             TabIndex="1" 
                             Visibility="Collapsed"
                             Margin="10 0 0 0"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="DayTextBox" 
                             IsEnabled="False"
                             Grid.Column="2" 
                             Text="{Binding Day, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             TextAlignment="Left"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Day" 
                             materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.RippleOnFocusEnabled="True"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                             materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.25"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             TabIndex="2" 
                             Visibility="Collapsed"
                             Margin="10 0 0 0"/>

                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="YearTextBox" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="YearTextBox" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="MonthTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DayTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="dummyTextBox" Property="Text" Value=" "/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="dummyTextBox" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Date, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

CustomDateTime.cs:

```
using System.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CustomDateTime
{
    public class CustomDateTime : Control
    {
        private TextBox YearTextBox;
        private TextBox MonthTextBox;
        private TextBox DayTextBox;

        static CustomDateTime()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDateTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomDateTime)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinYearProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MinYear", typeof(int), typeof(CustomDateTime), new PropertyMetadata(int.MinValue));
        public int MinYear
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MinYearProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinYearProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxYearProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxYear", typeof(int), typeof(CustomDateTime), new PropertyMetadata(int.MaxValue));
        public int MaxYear
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxYearProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxYearProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDateTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDateChanged));
        public string Date
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty YearProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Year", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDateTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDatePartChanged));
        private string Year
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(YearProperty); }
            set { SetValue(YearProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MonthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Month", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDateTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDatePartChanged));
        private string Month
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MonthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MonthProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Day", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDateTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDatePartChanged));
        private string Day
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DayProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DayProperty, value); }
        }



        public CustomDateTime()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            // Get the TextBox references
            YearTextBox = GetTemplateChild("YearTextBox") as TextBox;
            MonthTextBox = GetTemplateChild("MonthTextBox") as TextBox;
            DayTextBox = GetTemplateChild("DayTextBox") as TextBox;


            //if (YearTextBox != null)
            //{
            //    YearTextBox.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(Year), 
            //                                                                                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged } );
            //}

            // Add event handlers to the TextBoxes
            if (YearTextBox != null && MonthTextBox != null && DayTextBox != null)
            {
                YearTextBox.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
                YearTextBox.Loaded += TextBox_Loaded;
                YearTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                MonthTextBox.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
                MonthTextBox.Loaded += TextBox_Loaded;
                MonthTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                DayTextBox.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisableAndEnableTextBoxes(sender as TextBox);
        }

        private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisableAndEnableTextBoxes(sender as TextBox);
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

            // Check if the entered text is not a digit
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, 0))
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Do not allow non-digit characters
                return;
            }

            string newText = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart) + e.Text + textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength);
            int value;

            // Validate the entire text of the TextBox
            if (!int.TryParse(newText, out value))
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Invalid integer format
                return;
            }

            // Check the maximum length based on the TextBox name
            if (textBox.Name == "YearTextBox" && newText.Length > 4 ||
                textBox.Name == "MonthTextBox" && newText.Length > 2 ||
                textBox.Name == "DayTextBox" && newText.Length > 2)
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Do not allow more characters than the specified length
                return;
            }

            // Validate the input based on the allowed range
            if (textBox.Name == "YearTextBox" && (value < MinYear || value > MaxYear) && newText.Length == 4 ||
                textBox.Name == "MonthTextBox" && (value < 1 || value > 12) ||
                textBox.Name == "DayTextBox" && (value < 1 || value > 30))
            {
                if (textBox.Name == "YearTextBox")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Year must be between {MinYear} and {MaxYear}");
                }

                if (textBox.Name == "MonthTextBox")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Month must be between 1 and 12");
                }

                if (textBox.Name == "DayTextBox")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Day must be between 1 and 30");
                }

                SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
                e.Handled = true; // Value is out of range
            }

            DisableAndEnableTextBoxes(textBox);
        }

        private static void OnDateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomDateTime customDateTime = (CustomDateTime)d;
            customDateTime.UpdateDateParts();
        }

        private static void OnDatePartChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomDateTime customDateTime = (CustomDateTime)d;
            customDateTime.UpdateDate();
        }

        //This method is used to Disable and Enable the TextBoxes based on the value of the Other TextBox
        //i.e if the YearTextBox has a valid value then enable the MonthTextBox, and if the MonthTextBox has a valid value then enable the DayTextBox
        private void DisableAndEnableTextBoxes(TextBox textBox)
        {
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                int value = 0;
                if (textBox.Text != "")
                {
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
                }

                if (textBox.Name == "YearTextBox")
                {
                    if (value >= MinYear & value <= MaxYear)
                    {
                        MonthTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MonthTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }


                if (textBox.Name == "MonthTextBox" & YearTextBox.IsEnabled == true)
                {
                    if (value >= 1 & value <= 12)
                    {
                        DayTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DayTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void UpdateDateParts()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date))
            {
                string[] parts = Date.Split('/');
                int day, month, year;

                if (parts.Length == 3)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out day) && day >= 1 && day <= 30 &&
                        int.TryParse(parts[1], out month) && month >= 1 && month <= 12 &&
                        int.TryParse(parts[2], out year) && year >= MinYear && year <= MaxYear)
                    {
                        Day = parts[0];
                        Month = parts[1];
                        Year = parts[2];
                    }
                }
                else if (parts.Length == 2)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out month) && month >= 1 && month <= 12 &&
                        int.TryParse(parts[1], out year) && year >= MinYear && year <= MaxYear)
                    {
                        Day = string.Empty; // No day provided
                        Month = parts[0];
                        Year = parts[1];
                    }
                }
                else if (parts.Length == 1)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out year) && year >= MinYear && year <= MaxYear)
                    {
                        Day = string.Empty; // No day provided
                        Month = string.Empty; // No month provided
                        Year = parts[0];
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // Clear all parts if Date is empty
                Day = string.Empty;
                Month = string.Empty;
                Year = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDate()
        {
            string date = ",,";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Day))
            {
                date = date.Insert(0, $"{Day}/");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Month))
            {
                date = date.Insert(date.IndexOf(',') + 1, $"{Month}/");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Year))
            {
                date = date.Insert(date.LastIndexOf(',') + 1, Year);
            }

            string[] parts = date.Split(',');
            date = "";

            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                date += part;
            }

            Date = date;
        }

    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace CustomDateTime
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<DataItem> _dataItems;

        public ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems
        {
            get { return _dataItems; }
            set
            {
                _dataItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            // Sample data for the grid
            DataItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>
            {
                new DataItem { Name = "Item 1", Date = "01/01/2022" },
                new DataItem { Name = "Item 2", Date = "05/02/2022" },
                new DataItem { Name = "Item 3", Date = "10/03/2022" }
            };
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _date;
        public string Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set
            {
                if (_date != value)
                {
                    _date = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**usage in XAML:**

```
            <local:CustomDateTime Date="{Binding DataItems/Date}"
                                  MinYear="1430"
                                  MaxYear="1445"
                                  />
```

***Here is the issue displayed as gif:***

[image]

Comment: A control must never set its own DataContext because doing so breaks the standard data binding behaviour.

Comment: The user's DataContext should be irrelevant to the CustomControl, i.e. it does not need to and should not rely on property names and data structures of the DC at design time. 
The control exposes DPs and the user feeds them with bindings (of its own choice).
The contract goes through public DPs (and sometimes events) only.

Comment: In your case it should be sufficient that the user code in XAML binds to the "Date" property with an input string of a text box. Within your code behind you then dispatch the date parts to the other three partial date properties (year, month day). But the control doesn't need to be aware of the the existence of a "DataItem" class and its inner structure. Anything concerning the DataItem class must be handled outside the custom control.